How to fix the error " Window was already created"?
I successfully implemented and receive the push notifications, but when I tap on the notification message my app started crash getting blank page and at the mean time, I can see the exception,
**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Window was already created'

Here, i have added the call trace,
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.RuntimeNativeMethods.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception   C#
    0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:13,5 C#
    0x1E in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:126,26  C#
    0x12 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.Microsoft.Maui.IWindow.Created at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Window\Window.cs:483,5    C#
    0xB in Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.AppHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<OnConfigureLifeCycle>b__2_0 at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Hosting\LifecycleEvents\AppHostBuilderExtensions.Android.cs:23,6 C#
    0xD in Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity. at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiAppCompatActivity.Lifecycle.cs:61,104  C#
    0x1F in Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.InvokeLifecycleEvents<Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.AndroidLifecycle.OnPostCreate> at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\LifecycleEvents\LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.cs:31,5   C#
    0x40 in Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity.OnPostCreate at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiAppCompatActivity.Lifecycle.cs:61,4   C#
    0x11 in Android.App.Activity.n_OnPostCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Android.App.Activity.cs:4488,4 C#
    0x9 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:125,5    C#

I couldn't find out the root cause for this issue. Anyone, help me with this issue and i couldn't find any discussions or solution related to this.

Modify the MainActivity's launch mode as SingleTask,SingleTop. Such as:
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme",LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,

